Why my mathematica files are opening in Wolfram CDF Player?
I am unable to figure out why my '.nb' files are opening in Wolfram CDF Player. Its not running the codes already computed in that sheet. Also, if I am opening a new worksheet, it is opening in the same format.
Please help me with the following questions:
How do I change it back so I will be able to do the computations? What is the purpose of this CDF player? How is it automatically, without my doing anything, changed to this format of player?

in Windows Start tpye 'Standard Apps" and select the 'by extension' link.

What operating system are you using?
